# torch stack producing wrong dimensions

Tags: pytorch

I am quite new to pytorch, and I am trying to create data within a dataloader and my code looks like so:

```
a=[]
.. within a for loop
self.a.append(torch.stack([b[ith_idx][j], \
b[ith_idx][rnd_dist], \
b[rnd_cls_idx][rnd_dist_rnd_cls]]\
))
self.c.append([1,0])
```

where, b is a python list of tensors. For example, the first element of `b` has shape `torch.Size([46, 3, 512, 512])` (3 channels 512 x 512).

```
        self.a = torch.stack(self.a)
        self.c = torch.tensor(self.c)
```

and I notice I have shapes of `[500,3,3,512,512]` and [500,2] for `a` and `b`, while I was expecting `500,3,3,512,512` and `500` as tensor shapes.

Any pointers as to why this is happening would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shape of `c` is `[500, 2]` because you are appending a list of two values, `[1,0]` each time to `c` inside the loop. If you append either `1` or `0` iteratively then you will have a list of `500` elements.

For instance, you can append `1` or `0` randomly like follows:

```
self.c.append(np.random.randint(2))  # import numpy as np
```

or

```
self.c.append(torch.randint(0,2,(1,)))
```